# change html element with JQuery toggle

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have an HTML input element that needs to change when toggle off using the JQuery `.toggleClass`, instead of the `'blur' event`. This is supposed to happen for each table row that is selected [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4bppa43/)

Comment: Please would people who down vote have the good manners to indicate the reason why. Otherwise the OP is left guessing and will feel alienated and not return. This is not meant to be your exclusive club.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i guess this is the closest solution i can come up with for your problem:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4bppa43/496/)

```
$(document).on("blur", "input", function () {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $(this).replaceWith("<p></p>");
    parent.find('p').text(txt);
});
```

Comment: What am I meant to see happen in the fiddle?

Comment: a click on the `p` element will make it an `input` element, while losing focus on the `input` element will change it back to a `p` element